# Webpack - SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, babeljs

I have introduced Webpack for Django and Vue. But I get an error.
I can't execute webpack. What this error?

```
$ node --use_strict ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js
node_modules/webpack-command/lib/cli.js:5
const { register } = require('./global');
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

Comment: What's your node version? Does it support Object destruction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to destructure a require call.
Node version must support destructuring. Another option is to compile with babel-node.

If node supports it (**node v6 and newer**), check if you export `register` in `./global.js`.

I made a demo for you [here](https://repl.it/repls/CreamySkinnyBrace)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to use your local webpack to build your app. In this case, you need to run this command:

```
./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

Moreover, you can add the script to package json to make it shorter:

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
}
```

You can also use `npx` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) to run local node_modules:

```
npx webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue by forcefully installing Webpack CLI.
My NodeJS version is 16.

To do this, run this command:

`npm install -D webpack-cli`